# Google Script - get SHA1 script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sha1

I cannot for the life of me get the below script to work.

```
function GetSHA1(input) {
  var rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, input);
  var txtHash = '';
  for (j = 0; j <rawHash.length; j++) {
    var hashVal = rawHash[j];
    if (hashVal < 0)
      hashVal += 256; 
    if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1)
     txtHash += "0";
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
    }
  return txtHash;
}
```

It returns the error

> Exception: Argument cannot be null: value GetSHA1 @ GetSHA1.gs:2

The script should generate a SHA1 hash of any cells specified in google sheets.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How are you using the `GetSHA1 ` function? What is the value / object passed as argument?

Comment: @Rubén i'm using "GetSHA1" to get the SHA1 of multiple cells in a Google Sheets equation such as "=GetSHA1(A2:E2)". 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### This works for me

```
function GetSHA1(input="0") {
  let rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, input);
  let txtHash = '';
  for (let j = 0; j <rawHash.length; j++) {
    let hashVal = rawHash[j];
    if (hashVal < 0)
      hashVal += 256; 
    if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1)
     txtHash += "0";
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
    }
  console.log(txtHash)
  return txtHash;
}
```

#### This does not

```
function GetSHA1(input=null) {
  let rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, input);
  let txtHash = '';
  for (let j = 0; j <rawHash.length; j++) {
    let hashVal = rawHash[j];
    if (hashVal < 0)
      hashVal += 256; 
    if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1)
     txtHash += "0";
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
    }
  console.log(txtHash)
  return txtHash;
}
```

Comment: Thanks the top one does work and prints a SHA1 in the console, but I still get an error in google sheets when running it. The error is below.

"Exception: The parameters (DigestAlgorithm,number[]) don't match the method signature for Utilities.computeDigest. (line 2)."

I think this is because in the top example the input in "0", so the script is outputting a SHA1 for "0" which is "b6589fc6ab0dc82cf12099d1c2d40ab994e8410c".

I need the script to output the SHA1 of multiple cells through an equation like...

"=GetSHA1(A2:E2)"

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I never use cell formulas.  If you can provide an algrebraic equation I can accomplish that for you.

Comment: @CHC if you want to process a range you can add the dedicated range formula like this: `function GetSHA1_range(range) { return [range[0].map(x => GetSHA1(x)).flat()] }` and use as `=GetSHA1_range(A2:E2)`